# Ajax doesn't pass the array value fully when using "document.getElementById().value" using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays

Here I have a javascript code and an ajax written within it. This javascript function is called on a button event, this function passes the array values a[SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,Sleep] to an PHP file which works correctly, But when I use "document.getElementById("Someid").value" to get the value of an input tag , it returns the value correctly but it passes only one of the array value not the entire array value to the PHP file on button click, but if I use "document.getElementById("Someid")" , it sends all the array values but not the value if the input field. I also tried "document.getElementsByName("Someid")" and "document.getElementsByTagName("Sometagname")"..
soo plz some one give me right way to fix this as soon as possible.

here is my javascript code

```
function colorchange(id) 
{

 var background = document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor;
 if(background == "rgb(255, 145, 0)")
 {
   document.getElementById(id).style.background = "rgb(26,255,0)";
 }
 else                                                               
 {
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = "rgb(255, 145, 0)"; 
 }
 var elem = document.getElementById(id);

if(id=="select")
 { 
  if (elem.innerHTML=="Ignore Select") 
  {
   elem.innerHTML = "Enable Select";
  }
  else
  { 
   elem.innerHTML = "Ignore Select"; 
  }
 }

if(id=="select1")
{
 if (elem.innerHTML=="Ignore Delete") 
 {
   elem.innerHTML = "Enable Delete";
  }
  else
  { 
  elem.innerHTML = "Ignore Delete";
  }
  }

  if(id=="select2")
  {
  if (elem.innerHTML=="Ignore Insert")
  {
    elem.innerHTML = "Enable Insert";
  } 
  else
  {
   elem.innerHTML = "Ignore Insert";
  }
  }

  if(id=="select3")
  {
   if (elem.innerHTML=="Ignore Update")
    {
    elem.innerHTML = "Enable Update";
    } 
    else
    {
    elem.innerHTML = "Ignore Update";
    }
  }

  if(id=="select4")
 {
  if (elem.innerHTML=="Ignore Sleep")
  {
    elem.innerHTML = "Enable Sleep";
  } 
  else
  {
   elem.innerHTML = "Ignore Sleep";
  }
  }
var ip1 = document.getElementById("my_ip").value; //check this
   //var ip1 = document.getElementsByName("my_ip")[0]; // check this 
   //var qwe=ip1.value;


    var send = document.getElementById("select");
    var send1 = document.getElementById("select1");
    var send2 = document.getElementById("select2");
     var send3 = document.getElementById("select3");
    var send4 = document.getElementById("select4");

   // var a= new Array(); 
   var a=[];

   if(send.innerHTML=="Enable Select")
   {
    a.push("SELECT");
   }
   else
   {
   }

   if(send1.innerHTML=="Enable Delete")
   {
    a.push("DELETE");
   }
   else
   {
   }

   if(send2.innerHTML=="Enable Insert")
   {
   a.push("INSERT");
   }
   else
   {
   }

   if(send3.innerHTML=="Enable Update")
   {
    a.push("UPDATE");
   }
   else
   {
   }

   if(send4.innerHTML=="Enable Sleep")
   {
   a.push("Sleep");
    }
   else
   {
   }
    var x = a.join();

   if (id=="")
   {
   document.getElementById("form2").innerHTML="";
   return;
   }
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
    document.getElementById("form2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","ignore.php?a="+x+"&ip2="+ip1,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  }
```

Here check the lines I have commented "//check this"

Comment: Some HTML would be helpful. And a jsfiddle even better.

Comment: Your JavaScript is hard to read due to bad indentation and very inefficient due to duplicate code and badly named elements. Also I don't understand your question/problem.